# Add text to tkinter with loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem. I want to simplify and explain the problem.
I have this code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

def do():
    global text
    for i in range(0, 10):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        text.insert(INSERT, i)

root = Tk()
global text
text = ScrolledText(root)
text.grid()
button = Button(root, text = 'insert', command = do)
button.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

It does a simple job. it has to open the root window and add a number to it every half second, but it does it all at once and after the loop is done.

Comment: see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-after-method-in-tkinter/

Comment: `global` on the main block does no good.

Comment: btw, when the Button executes do(), there are no GUI updates possible until it returns and mainloop can take over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your looking for how to use `after(ms,func)`, this is how your function should look like:

```
lst = [_ for _ in range(10)] #list of numbers to index through
count = 0 #index number
def do():
    global count 
    text.insert(INSERT,lst[count]) #insert the current element onto the textbox
    count += 1 #increase the index number
    
    rep = root.after(500, do) #repeat the function
    if count >= len(lst): #if index number greater than length of items in list
        root.after_cancel(rep) #stop repeating
```

and `root.after_cancel(id)` will cancel the repetition. Using `global` outside the functions holds no good.